# Overwrite getter logic for an instance of Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I am using [immutable.js](/questions/tagged/immutable.js) to manage configuration object, e.g.

`config.js`

```js
export default Immutable.fromJS({
    foo: 'FOO',
    bar: {
        // ...
    }
});
```

I would like to overwrite the getter functions so that accessing an `undefined` property would throw an error.

How do I do it given that every setter method of the resulting object will create a new instance of Immutable (in effect overwriting whatever monkey-patching)?

Comment: You could try forking it?

Comment: Or, treating this as an XY problem, you could export a getter (instead of the config object itself) which throws the error if the property is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I do not want it to throw an error, just handle undefined without causing the code to break fatally. To throw specific error I might use try/catch, but this is highly inefficient.

To prevent breakage I do something like this.

My motivation here is mostly that my call .get of undefined poops itself really hard, and initializing properly all over the place helps, but doesn't catch all edge cases. I just want the data or undefined without any breakage. Specific type checking causes me to do more work later if I want it to make changes.

This looser version solves many more edge cases(most if not all extend type Iterable which has .get, and all data is eventually gotten) than a specific type check does(which usually only saves you when you try to update on the wrong type etc).

```
/* getValid: Checks for valid ImmutableJS type Iterable

    returns valid Iterable, valid Iterable child data, or undefined

    Iterable.isIterable(maybeIterable) && maybeIterable.get(['data', key], Map()), becomes
    getValid(maybeIterable, ['data', key], Map())

    But wait! There's more! As a result:
    getValid(maybeIterable) returns the maybeIterable or undefined 
    and we can still say getValid(maybeIterable, null, Map()) returns the maybeIterable or Map()            */

export const getValid = (maybeIterable, path, getInstead) =>
  Iterable.isIterable(maybeIterable) && path
    ? ((typeof path === 'object' && maybeIterable.getIn(path, getInstead)) || maybeIterable.get(path, getInstead))
    : Iterable.isIterable(maybeIterable) && maybeIterable || getInstead;


//Here is an untested version that a friend requested. It is slightly easier to grok.

export const getValid = (maybeIterable, path, getInstead) => {
  if(valid(maybeIterable)) {                 // Check if it is valid
    if(path) {                                        // Check if it has a key
      if(typeof path === 'object') {     // Check if it is an 'array'
        return maybeIterable.getIn(path, getInstead) // Get your stuff
      } else {
        maybeIterable.get(path, getInstead)          // Get your stuff
      }
    } else {
      return maybeIterable || getInstead;                 // No key? just return the valid Iterable
    }
  } else {
    return undefined;                       // Not valid, return undefined, perhaps should return false here
  }
}
```

Just give me what I am asking for or tell me no. Don't explode. I believe underscore does something similar also.